# Import HDFS data file into mysql

Tags: mysql, hadoop, mysqlimport

I am trying to import a large HDFS file into a mysql db. The data in the file is delimiter by a '^A'. How do I tell mysql to separate each column by ctrl-A? Also, is it possible for me to specify what fields I want to import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlimport.html

You are looking for the `--fields-terminated-by=string` option.  There is not option to only select certain fields for import, though you can use `--columns=column_list` to map columns in your data to fields in the table.